# what does the function(respsonse,status) mean in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to create a route planner for a school project and I need to annotate my code to explain what it means/does. Since my JavaScript/Google Maps knowledge is limited and I can't find anything on here, I was wondering what does the following code do/mean.

```
function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
```

Comment: Hello Henry, welcome to StackOverflow, remember this community is intended for specific questions and answers. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and avoid asking someone else to do your own research. Help us keep the good value of the site.

Comment: Thanks, but I believe my question was very specific, I probably just needed to spend more time researching.

Comment: This is part of an anonymous callback function which is executed after something else occurs (like, an ajax request completes, and this function handles the response).  The parameters `response` and `status` are provided by the calling mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the names of the parameters in your function I infer it is related to HTTP requests, responses and status.

In HTTP, a response is the complete (as its name states) response of a request, the status is one of many different HTTP status, it has an equivalent status code. You can learn about them [everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

A status `200` means `OK` which is the one in your condition. You may be familiar with the following status:

1. `404`: Not found
2. `500`: Internal server error

In your function, `response` may be the result of a HTTP call containing some valuable data that you bounce to the function `directionsDisplay.setDirections`.

Exactly what it does depends on the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read up on them, like you said I am familiar with the 404 and 500, but I have never come across the response,status syntax before, thanks for the help!